# Pygame event inside class not recognized

Tags: python, pygame

I have completed a game using pygame without any problems. Now I am trying to organise the code and add classes. However, I am having a problem with the event command.

I tried using `pygame.event.poll()` and `pygame.event.get()`, but neither helped.

```
class MainRun():
    run = True
    def Main(self):
        #some code
        while MainRun.run:
            pygame.time.delay(35)
             for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    MainRun.run = False
            a.activate_skills()

class Player():
     #code
     def activate_skills(self):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #some code

a = Player
main = MainRun().Main()
```

> if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: NameError: name 'event' is not defined

So how can I define the event? Please see what I have already tried.

Comment: You can use `pygame.event.get` inside the `activate_skills` method.

Comment: That also didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call `pygame.event.get()` once, as it will fetch all the events that have happened. For example:

```
a = pygame.event.get()  # Contains the events that has happen.
for event in a:
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit()

b = pygame.event.get()  # Will probably contain nothing, as the code above took the events from the event queue. 
for event in b:
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        do_something()

do_some_calculation()
c = pygame.event.get()  # Might contain something, if the user did something during the time it took to do the calculation.
for event in c:
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        do_other_thing()
```

In the above example, it's likely `do_something()` will never be called, as the event queue has been cleared just before. `do_other_thing()` might be called, but that's **only** if the user pressed the button during the time it took to execute `do_some_calculations()`. If the user pressed before or after, the click event will have been cleared and lost.

So in your situation, you could do something like this:

```
class MainRun():
    run = True
    def Main(self):
        #some code
        while MainRun.run:
            pygame.time.delay(35)
             for event in pygame.event.get():  # ONLY CALLED HERE IN THE ENTIRE PROGRAM.
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    MainRun.run = False
                a.activate_skills(event)  # MOVED THIS INTO THE FOR LOOP!

class Player():
     #code
     def activate_skills(self, event):  # TAKING THE EVENT AS PARAMETER.
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #some code

a = Player
main = MainRun().Main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works for you :D

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        # your code
```

Comment: Alright this seems to work but is it efficient to use the repetition 2 times? I mean one in main and one in player

Comment: As you're working with `event's` you need this every time, even on separate classes.

Comment: @Jordan Don't do this. `pygame.event.get()` should really only be called once each frame. That's because the function **clears all events** from the internal event queue, which means that if you don't handle *all* events in the event loop, then you'll potentially be clearing events from the user.

Comment: @ExecutionerAxe Calling `pygame.event.get()` will clear the event queue, so doing this in every class will remove all events that aren't handled. It might work, but you'll most likely be throwing away many of the users clicks and other events.